# How to create paginated listings of included php files

Tags: php, include, pagination

I'm a complete newbie in php.
So I have this script which includes all *.php files found in the "items" directory.

```
<?php
foreach (glob("products/items/*.php") as $filename)
{
include $filename;
}?>
```

How exactly would I go about making the result show in separate pages (for example: 5 items (*.php files) max per each page)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your PHP script will just construct one page. That page being composed of all the `.php` files from the `items` directory one after another.

You need to write the code to select the appropriate files according to the users selection.

Comment: it selects the files I need, I simply need to divide the entire result into separate pages (1, 2, 3, etc) so that the page wouldn't end up a mile long

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make the pagination from ground up in php, then here is a tutorial (replace the mysql info with your php files info): [click](http://www.phpfreaks.com/tutorial/basic-pagination)

Or you can use one of the many jQuery plugins: [list of plugins](http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/10-jquery-pagination-plugins/)